# Removing an appended style sheet on button's second click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm just getting started with JS, and I cant seem to figure this out.

I have a very simple script:

```
function nightmode() {
    var oLink = document.createElement("link") 
    oLink.href = "nightmode2.css";
    oLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    oLink.type = "text/css"; 
    document.body.appendChild(oLink);
```

And a button:

```
<button onclick="nightmode()">Night Mode</button>
```

And, all in all, this works great.

However, I'd like a second click to remove the stylesheet. So is there any way to get `nightmode()` to reverse itself on a second run, then run properly on a third, and reverse on the fourth, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle the functionality by just adding an ID, and checking for it

```
function nightmode(){
    var el = document.getElementById('myStyles'); // get stylesheet

    if ( el !== null ) {                // if it exists
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);  // remove it
    } else {                            // if not, add it
        var oLink = document.createElement("link") 

        oLink.id   = 'myStyles';
        oLink.href = "nightmode2.css";
        voLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
        oLink.type = "text/css"; 

        document.body.appendChild(oLink);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much- I was trying to remove oLink like an idiot. This works much better.

Answer (score 1):

add a variable:

```
var clicks = 0;
```

outside nightmode
inside nightmode put:

```
if (clicks % 2 == 1)
{
    //existing code
}
else
{
     //remove css
}
clicks++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Modulous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (%) operator to achieve this by incrementing a count of the times you click the button to toggle the night mode.

```
var nightModeCount = 0;
function nightmode() {

    if((nightModeCount % 2) == 1) {
        //add the stylesheet
        var oLink = document.createElement("link") 
        oLink.href = "nightmode2.css";
        oLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
        oLink.type = "text/css"; 
        document.body.appendChild(oLink);
    } else {
        //find the stylesheet in the dom
        var oLink = document.querySelectorAll("link[href=nightmode2.css]");
        //remove it
        oLink.parentNode.removeChild(oLink);
    }

    nightModeCount++;
}
```

***Side note,*** it might be better to add this behaviour of this nightmode2.css by incorporating your normal and nightmode CSS into the same stylesheet and just toggling the presence of a class on the body element.

*Inserting and removing a stylesheet like you are doing has considerable overhead in comparison to just toggling a class.*